# R version of sklearn's GroupKFold

Tags: r, r-caret, cross-validation

I working on a cross validation in which samples from the same group cannot be in both train and test.

Python has the sklearn function GroupKFold.

Does R or caret have similar?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is named groupKFold() in caret